# Convert epoch timestamp to normal timestamp in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to convert the epoch timestamp to a normal timestamp.

i have tried `${field.value:format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS')}` in update attribute it give some wrong date in 1970 for the value `1625777940`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have epoch timestamp in seconds then converting it to java is simply multiply by 1000 because java counts time in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 (the same base as unix).

so, this should work:

```js
${field.value:multiply(1000):format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS')}
```

Comment: Yes its working